# I'm not able to use wireshark "couldn't run /usr/bin/dumpcap in child process"

Tags: wireshark

This message appears:

```
No interface can be used for capturing in this system with the current configuration.

(couldn't run /usr/bin/dumpcap in child process: permission denied)
```

Tell me how to avoid it.

Comment: you could run it temporary as root - this would be a workaround regarding the missing interfaces. Wireshark should display a dialog/warning regarding root usage in that case

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As @Tim already mentioned - this problem was discussed before already.
[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348712/there-are-no-interfaces-on-which-a-capture-can-be-done) gives the proper solution - just tested it in 14.04 and it is still valid & working

The following is a 100% quote from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348712/there-are-no-interfaces-on-which-a-capture-can-be-done).

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

press the right arrow and enter for yes

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

you should now be able to run it without root and you will be able to capture.

Comment: For me its enough  `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap`

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 only with the `chmod...`

Comment: ```sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap``` was the only missing step.

I granted root privileges to all users during wireshark installation so no need to run dpkg-reconfigure.

Comment: Rather than `chmod` the binary to allow unprivileged access, add your account to the `wireshark` group that the reconfiguration creates, then log out & in again or reboot for the membership to take effect.